# how to check if a string contains an alphanum chars appears at least n times consecutively

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I am testing for a string if it contains at least n chars in consecutive order:

I have this regex but it doesn't seems to work

```
(\w\1){3,}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(\w)\1{3,}` This makes sure that you have a character repeating at least four times.

The problem with `(\w\1)` is that the backreference `\1` is inside the capturing group itself. `\1` refers to the character(s) matched by the first parenthetical `()` group.

If you want to capture the whole matched string, enclose the regex in another parenthetical group.

```
((\w)\2{3,})
```

Note that here the index of backreference is `\2` as `\1` refers to the outer parentheses.

Check the example:

```
Regex      : ((\w)\2{3,})
TestString : bbaaaaaacc
Match      : aaaaaa
$1         : aaaaaa
$2         : a
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for n of the same character or just n characters?

`(\w)\1{2,}` finds one character and then two more of the same. So it will match if you have 3 or more of the same char consecutive order in the string.

`(\w){3,}` will match 3 or more characters.